# Variable value in codeigniter views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to pass a variable from a controller to a view. I have some code but in order to understand what is the problem I made it simple. Here is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        $p=2;

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('welcome_message',$p);
        }
    }

?>
```

Variable p is declared in the view.

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
    <?php echo $p?>
</div>
```

When I try to display the $p value, I obtained the error:

**ERROR**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$p' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\wamp\www\..\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 20
```

What's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of variables need to be passed as an array ([check out the docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)).

```
$data = array(
               'title' => 'My Title',
               'heading' => 'My Heading',
               'message' => 'My Message'
          );

$this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
```

$p has been declared out of the scope of the function, so either;

```
public function index() {
   $p = 2;
   $this->load->view('welcome_message',array('p' => $p));
}
```

or

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

public $p=2;

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',array('p' => $this->p));
}
}
```

Comment: Yes. it works now. But when I changed in my real code I have another error: 

    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Notice

    Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$arrPermisos

    Filename: marketing/campanas.php

    Line Number: 6

The controller code: `public function index()
 { $this->load->view("marketing/campanas",$this->arrPermisos); }` The view code: `<ul class="menuArea">
      <?php if ($this->arrPermisos["campanas_leer"]) { ?>
      <li class="current"><a href="/comercial/campanas/">CampaÃ±as</a></li>
      <?php } ?>
     </ul> ` What's wrong?

Comment: @axmug is $this->arrPermisos a hash array?

Comment: Yes. It is an array where roles users are saved.

Comment: when referencing in the view code you need to use the key of the array element as the variable. E.g in controller array('foo' => 1) then when passed into your view access it by $foo

Comment: Yes. I tried it but it doesn't work. And I don't know why. If I type: `<?php if ($arrPermisos["campanas_leer"]) { ?> <li class="current"><a href="/comercial/campanas/">CampaÃ±as</a></li> <?php }` the error is undefined variable arrPermisos.

Comment: if that is how you want to access it in controller do $this->load->view("marketing/campanas", array('arrPermisos' => $this->arrPermisos));

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$p`in your controller's constructor:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
        $this->p = 2;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['p'] = $this->p;
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

?>